# How to change value in String in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, jwt, passport.js

I am generating JWT token and in there I have to pass expirein arguement which should be in string and that value is coming from credentials. this is code please tell me how can I change this value to a string.

```
const generateToken = ({ id, errorMessage, secret }) => {
  try {
    const token = jwt.sign({ id }, secret, {
      expiresIn:JSON.stringify(`${config.SESSION_DURATION * 60 * 1000}`),
    });
    return token;
  } catch (err) {
    throw errorMessage || err;
  }
};
```

this above code generating a error like this

```
"\"expiresIn\" should be a number of seconds or string representing a timespan eg: \"1d\", \"20h\", 60"
```

and this is how I am passing this token as a cookies maybe this error come from here

```
res
        .cookie("jwt_auth", token, {
          maxAge: config.SESSION_DURATION * 60 * 1000,    //it should be in miliseconds 
          // maxAge: 3600000,  
          httpOnly: true,
          sameSite: true,
          secure: config.NODE_ENV === "development",
        })
        .redirect(config.CLIENT_URL);
```

Comment: The error says it all, no? So, either no `JSON.stringify` call (and use a *numeric value* **in seconds** -- not milliseconds) or suffix the unit of measure, as given as examples in the error message itself. Rarely are error messages so helpful, so make use of that info.

Comment: Both maxAge and expireIn take values in seconds?

Comment: Your comment in the code says that `maxAge` takes milliseconds, so I wont comment on that. But the error message concerning `expireIn` explicitly says "seconds", or am I missing something? Do you read something else in that error message?

Comment: I assume it's an [express session](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html) package and `maxAge` is in milliseconds while JsonWebToken `expireIn` is seconds or [ms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms) format string

Answer (score 0):

It gives a type error.

It Expects a number and you are passing a string (also it's seconds not millis).

When its string then should be '1s', '2m', ... its an npm library `ms` https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms.

Either use that `ms` compatible value or number.

This should work.

```js
const generateToken = ({ id, errorMessage, secret }) => {
  try {
    const token = jwt.sign({ id }, secret, {
      expiresIn: Number(config.SESSION_DURATION),
    });
    return token;
  } catch (err) {
    throw errorMessage || err;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to pass

```
let x = config.SESSION_DURATION * 60 * 1000
...
maxAge: x.toString()
...
```

or use the string '365d' as the error message is pointing out